# How can i format 07/03/2012 to March 7th,2012 in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

Any one please help
i need to show the date 03/03/2012 as March 3rd,2012 etc

Comment: Does it have to do the "rd" in "3rd"? Looking at the standard and custom format strings available none of them will do this for you... Its relatively easy without though. :)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can create your own custom format provider to do this:

```
public class MyCustomDateProvider: IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
            return this;

        return null;
    }

    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        if (!(arg is DateTime)) throw new NotSupportedException();

        var dt = (DateTime) arg;

        string suffix;

        if (new[] {11, 12, 13}.Contains(dt.Day))
        {
            suffix = "th";
        }
        else if (dt.Day % 10 == 1)
        {
            suffix = "st";
        }
        else if (dt.Day % 10 == 2)
        {
            suffix = "nd";
        }
        else if (dt.Day % 10 == 3)
        {
            suffix = "rd";
        }
        else
        {
            suffix = "th";
        }

        return string.Format("{0:MMMM} {1}{2}, {0:yyyy}", arg, dt.Day, suffix);
    }
}
```

This can then be called like this:

```
var formattedDate = string.Format(new MyCustomDateProvider(), "{0}", date);
```

Resulting in (for example):

> March 3rd, 2012

Comment: but need to check  if (dt.Day == 11 || dt.Day == 12 || dt.Day == 13)
            {
                suffix = "th";
                return string.Format("{0:MMMM} {1}{2}, {0:yyyy}", arg, dt.Day, suffix);
            }

Comment: oh yes - you'll have to add them as special cases, before the other checks.

Comment: Short version of this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2050854/581414

Answer (score 31):

[Humanizer](https://github.com/MehdiK/Humanizer/blob/master/readme.md) meets all your .NET needs for manipulating and displaying strings, enums, dates, times, timespans, numbers and quantities

To install Humanizer, run the following command in the Package Manager Console

```
PM> Install-Package Humanizer
```

Ordinalize turns a number into an ordinal string used to denote the position in an ordered sequence such as 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th:

```
1.Ordinalize() => "1st"
5.Ordinalize() => "5th"
```

Then you can use:

```
String.Format("{0} {1:MMMM yyyy}", date.Day.Ordinalize(), date)
```

Comment: +1 - I used String.Format("{0} {1}", d.Day.Ordinalize(), d.ToString("MMMM yyyy"))

Comment: +1 Humanizer is awesome. btw you can write:
string.Format("{0} {1:MMMM yyyy}", date.Day.Ordinalize(), date)

Comment: Good one @BritishDeveloper, I'll update the example

Comment: Is there a way to parse a British date with Humanizer? Like parse "8th Nov 2012" into a proper DateTime object.

Answer (score 13):

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

```
date.ToString("MMMM d, yyyy")
```

Or if you need the "rd" too:

```
string.Format("{0} {1}, {2}", date.ToString("MMMM"), date.Day.Ordinal(), date.ToString("yyyy"))
```

- the `Ordinal()` method can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20166/139300)

Comment: This doesn't quite give the right format due to the "rd" in the original spec.

Comment: should be string.Format("{0} {1}, {2}", DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM"), Ordinal(DateTime.Now.Day), DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"))

Answer (score 3):

No, there is nothing in string.Format() that will give you ordinals (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th and so on).

You can combine the date format like suggested in other answers, with your own ordinal as suggested for example in this answer

[Is there an easy way to create ordinals in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-ordinals-in-c)

```
string Format(DateTime date)
{
    int dayNo = date.Day;
    return string.Format("{0} {1}{2}, {3}", 
                date.ToString("MMMM"), dayNo, AddOrdinal(dayNo), date.Year); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static class IntegerExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// converts an integer to its ordinal representation
    /// </summary>
    public static String AsOrdinal(this Int32 number)
    {
        if (number < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("number");

        var work = number.ToString("n0");

        var modOf100 = number % 100;

        if (modOf100 == 11 || modOf100 == 12 || modOf100 == 13)
            return work + "th";

        switch (number % 10)
        {
            case 1:
                work += "st"; break;
            case 2:
                work += "nd"; break;
            case 3:
                work += "rd"; break;
           default:
                work += "th"; break;
        }

        return work;
    }
}
```

Proof:

```
[TestFixture]
class IntegerExtensionTests
{
    [Test]
    public void TestCases_1s_10s_100s_1000s()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("1st", 1.AsOrdinal());
        Assert.AreEqual("2nd", 2.AsOrdinal());
        Assert.AreEqual("3rd", 3.AsOrdinal());

        foreach (var integer in Enumerable.Range(4, 6))
            Assert.AreEqual(String.Format("{0:n0}th", integer), integer.AsOrdinal());

        Assert.AreEqual("11th", 11.AsOrdinal());
        Assert.AreEqual("12th", 12.AsOrdinal());
        Assert.AreEqual("13th", 13.AsOrdinal());

        foreach (var integer in Enumerable.Range(14, 6))
            Assert.AreEqual(String.Format("{0:n0}th", integer), integer.AsOrdinal());

        Assert.AreEqual("21st", 21.AsOrdinal());
        Assert.AreEqual("22nd", 22.AsOrdinal());
        Assert.AreEqual("23rd", 23.AsOrdinal());

        foreach (var integer in Enumerable.Range(24, 6))
            Assert.AreEqual(String.Format("{0:n0}th", integer), integer.AsOrdinal());

        Assert.AreEqual("31st", 31.AsOrdinal());
        Assert.AreEqual("32nd", 32.AsOrdinal());
        Assert.AreEqual("33rd", 33.AsOrdinal());

        //then just jump to 100

        Assert.AreEqual("101st", 101.AsOrdinal());
        Assert.AreEqual("102nd", 102.AsOrdinal());
        Assert.AreEqual("103rd", 103.AsOrdinal());

        foreach (var integer in Enumerable.Range(104, 6))
            Assert.AreEqual(String.Format("{0:n0}th", integer), integer.AsOrdinal());

        Assert.AreEqual("111th", 111.AsOrdinal());
        Assert.AreEqual("112th", 112.AsOrdinal());
        Assert.AreEqual("113th", 113.AsOrdinal());

        foreach (var integer in Enumerable.Range(114, 6))
            Assert.AreEqual(String.Format("{0:n0}th", integer), integer.AsOrdinal());

        Assert.AreEqual("121st", 121.AsOrdinal());
        Assert.AreEqual("122nd", 122.AsOrdinal());
        Assert.AreEqual("123rd", 123.AsOrdinal());

        foreach (var integer in Enumerable.Range(124, 6))
            Assert.AreEqual(String.Format("{0:n0}th", integer), integer.AsOrdinal());

        //then just jump to 1000

        Assert.AreEqual("1,001st", 1001.AsOrdinal());
        Assert.AreEqual("1,002nd", 1002.AsOrdinal());
        Assert.AreEqual("1,003rd", 1003.AsOrdinal());

        foreach (var integer in Enumerable.Range(1004, 6))
            Assert.AreEqual(String.Format("{0:n0}th", integer), integer.AsOrdinal());

        Assert.AreEqual("1,011th", 1011.AsOrdinal());
        Assert.AreEqual("1,012th", 1012.AsOrdinal());
        Assert.AreEqual("1,013th", 1013.AsOrdinal());

        foreach (var integer in Enumerable.Range(1014, 6))
            Assert.AreEqual(String.Format("{0:n0}th", integer), integer.AsOrdinal());

        Assert.AreEqual("1,021st", 1021.AsOrdinal());
        Assert.AreEqual("1,022nd", 1022.AsOrdinal());
        Assert.AreEqual("1,023rd", 1023.AsOrdinal());

        foreach (var integer in Enumerable.Range(1024, 6))
            Assert.AreEqual(String.Format("{0:n0}th", integer), integer.AsOrdinal());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on Rob Levine's answer and the comments on that answer... I've adapted as an extension method on DateTime so you can just call:

```
var formattedDate = date.Friendly();
```

Here's the extension method:

```
public static class DateFormatter
{
  public static string Friendly(this DateTime dt)
  {
    string suffix;

    switch (dt.Day)
    {
      case 1:
      case 21:
      case 31:
        suffix = "st";
        break;
      case 2:
      case 22:
        suffix = "nd";
        break;
      case 3:
      case 23:
        suffix = "rd";
        break;
      default:
        suffix = "th";
        break;
    }

    return string.Format("{0:MMMM} {1}{2}, {0:yyyy}", dt, dt.Day, suffix);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version of the Ordinalize() extension, short and sweet:

```
public static string Ordinalize(this int x)
{
    var xString = x.ToString();
    var xLength = xString.Length;
    var xLastTwoCharacters = xString.Substring(Math.Max(0, xLength - 2));
    return xString + 
        ((x % 10 == 1 && xLastTwoCharacters != "11") 
            ? "st"
        : (x % 10 == 2 && xLastTwoCharacters != "12") 
            ? "nd"
        : (x % 10 == 3 && xLastTwoCharacters != "13") 
            ? "rd"
        : "th");
    }
```

and then call that extension like this

```
myDate.Day.Ordinalize()
```

or

```
myAnyNumber.Ordinalize()
```

Comment: What about 211?

Comment: @Kristopher  nice - I think I fixed it this time. here is a tester on .NetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hy3OoI

Answer (score -3):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(args);
String.Format("{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}", dt);
```

// "Sun, Mar 9, 2008"

Answer (score -4):

Use following Code:

```
DateTime thisDate1 = new DateTime(2011, 6, 10);
Console.WriteLine("Today is " + thisDate1.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy") + ".");

DateTimeOffset thisDate2 = new DateTimeOffset(2011, 6, 10, 15, 24, 16, 
                                              TimeSpan.Zero);
Console.WriteLine("The current date and time: {0:MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss zzz}", 
                   thisDate2); 
// The example displays the following output:
//    Today is June 10, 2011.
//    The current date and time: 06/10/11 15:24:16 +00:00
```

Comment: This isn't what was asked....