# Re-format datetime to 7th November 2014

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have myself a `DateTime` variable of

```
7/11/2014
```

and I want to convert that date to display as

```
7th November 2014
```

What format do I use? I have tried `ToLongDateString` but it misses the suffix of the day date.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050805/getting-day-suffix-when-using-datetime-tostring

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-ordinals-in-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9601593/497356

Comment: try: `string output = YourDateTime.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))` . This will be displaying the outputs always in English.

Comment: @ChrisB That does not add the "th" that the OP wants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe there's any direct support for ordinals ("st", "nd", "th") within .NET. If you only need to support English, I suggest you hard code it yourself. For example:

```
string text = string.Format("{0}{1} {2} {3}", dt.Day, GetOrdinal(dt.Day),
                            dt.ToString("MMMM"), dt.Year);
```

(Where you'd write `GetOrdinal` yourself.) Note that this assumes you want *exactly* this format - different cultures (even within English) may prefer `November 7th 2014` for example.

If you need to support all kinds of languages, it becomes very difficult - different languages have some *very* different approaches to ordinals.

Side-note: Even [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) doesn't handle this yet. I hope to eventually implement some [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org) support, which should *in theory* handle it for all locales. We'll see...

Comment: Also consider making this format an extension method of DateTime and stick it into your personal standard library.

Comment: As a side note, [Humanizer](http://humanizr.net/) is a great .NET project for converting numbers into ordinal or cardinal or anything else.

Comment: @icemanind: Interesting. It doesn't seem to be using CLDR data, which seems a little unfortunate, but still an interesting project.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I think you are correct. But being an open source project, hopefully, one day, CLDR data can be programmed into it. It'll probably be a large undertaking unfortunately.