# Changing DateTime format to dd/mmmm/yyyy

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a DateTime object in the format of `6/07/2016`, and I want to change it to be in the format of `6th July 2016`.

How can I do this in C#? Been looking around but only seem to find ways to turn strings into DateTime in this format. What if I already have a DateTime object? Convert to string first?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on where you are using `6th July 2016`, show your code where you would display the datetime to the user.

Comment: `timeToRun.ToShortDateString()` returns `6/07/2016`

Comment: Are the date suffixes (-th, -st, -nd...) required, or can it just be 6 July 2016?

Comment: Doesn't need date suffixes. Thanks

Comment: Then yea, go with @ScottChamberlain's answer

Comment: `DateTime` **does not** have a format. It's just a value. From memory the underlying value is just a `ulong`. It's only when you convert it to a string that you impose a format - like when you call `.ToLongDateString()`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass in the string format in the `.ToString` call, referencing the [custom date and time format specifier page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) to see which specifiers you need.

```
string timeString = timeToRun.ToString("d MMMM yyyy")
```

This will give you `6 July 2016`, if you want `6th` instead of `6` you need a custom format provider [as specified in this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601593/how-can-i-format-07-03-2012-to-march-7th-2012-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

I think this code piece can help you.

This [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601593/how-can-i-format-07-03-2012-to-march-7th-2012-in-c-sharp) also help me to understand it

```
ChangeIt(DateTime.Parse("16/07/2016"));

public static string ChangeIt(DateTime date)
{
     switch(date.Day)
     {
        case 1:
        case 21:
        case 31:
           return date.ToString("d'st' MMMM yyyy");
        case 2:
        case 22:
           return date.ToString("d'nd' MMMM yyyy");
        case 3:
        case 23:
           return date.ToString("d'rd' MMMM yyyy");
        default:
           return date.ToString("d'th' MMMM yyyy");
      }
}
```