# How to get dates in M YYMMDD SS manner

Tags: c#

I'm having a readonly `text box` and a `button` in `C#`.
When I'm clicking on button it should display in a text box in below manner:

> MYYMMJJSS.

`M`: Manual, `YY`: The last digits of year, `MM`: The month, `JJ`: The Day, `SS`: The Sequence for the concerned Day

Examples: 
•   On `1st February 2019`, a first order is created by user. The system proposes this value `M19020101`.

•   On `1st February 2019`, a second manual order is created by user. The system proposes this value `M19020102`.

Can anyone helps me to understand how can i add a `M` (manual) and Sequence number in the dates?

Comment: What you tried so far? We are here to help not to work for you. What part is a problem? Where are you struggling? Post a [MCVE] even with pseudo code.

Comment: Tried reading this ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: Try this, it is similar to what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601593/how-can-i-format-07-03-2012-to-march-7th-2012-in-c-sharp

Comment: I tried:   private void NumberValidationTxtNFab()
        {
            int index = 1;
            var dates = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMdd");
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dates))
            {
                dates = "M" + dates + "0" + index;
                index++;
            }
            var _txtNFab = txtNFab.Text;
                _txtNFab = dates;
        }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i format 07/03/2012 to March 7th,2012 in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601593/how-can-i-format-07-03-2012-to-march-7th-2012-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int sequenceNumber = 12;
        string theString = string.Format("M{0}{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMdd"), sequenceNumber);
        Console.WriteLine(theString);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way:

```
int sequenceNumber = 1;
string text = $"M{DateTime.Now:yyMMdd}{sequenceNumber:D2}";
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

- `yyMMdd`: format datetime to string
- `D2`: format integer so it contain at least 2 digits

Based on your new comment, you can rewrite your code something similar to:

```
int index = 1;

private void NumberValidationTxtNFab()
{
    txtNFab.Text = $"M{DateTime.Now:yyMMdd}{index:D2}";
    index++;
}
```

Comment: private void NumberValidationTxtNFab()
        {
            int index = 1;
            var dates = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMdd");
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dates))
            {
                dates = "M" + dates + "0" + index;
                index++;
            }
            var _txtNFab = txtNFab.Text;
                _txtNFab = dates;
        }

Comment: @Naman if index is 1, your code will output `M18072501` (9 chars), but if index is 11, it will output `M180725011` (10 chars), meanwhile my code will output `M18072511` (still 9 chars)

Comment: its working for first time, M18072501 but second time if i click it is showing same "M18072501" instead of "M18072502".

Comment: @Naman, you must put the `index` variable outside the function. You can see my edit

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTime.ToString()` supports escaping literals. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#character-literals and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#escape

But for the sequence number you need either legacy or new way of interpolation as suggested by others, or concatenation.