# DateTime Feature in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

I have to retrieve a date from the database in format YYYY-MM-DD and display it as the format:

> Mon 25th

Currently my code looks like:

```
Label fixtureDateLabel = new Label();
fixtureDateLabel.Text = dReaderGameweekFixtures["fixtureDate"].ToString();
```

How do I adapt this to display in the format I want?

Comment: The `DATETIME` you're getting from the database (assuming SQL Server) doesn't have **any** string format - **you** define what the format should be, when calling `.ToString()` on it...

Comment: Is your date stored in the DB as text, or as a `datetime` value?

Comment: Your question is not clear and is lacking some details.. please improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the `ToString` method:

```
var result = DateTime.Parse(
  dReaderGameweekFixtures["fixtureDate"].ToString()
).ToString("ddd dd");
```

To my knowledge you'll need a little something extra to formulate the suffix to the day number, which is [already conveniently provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050805/getting-day-suffix-when-using-datetime-tostring).

Comment: That'll only show "Mon 25" not "25th"... The "th" suffix is actually quite tricky.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Yes, and it's already been covered here on SO, I wasn't about to redo it, but had to find it.

Comment: Maybe you don't need the ToString/Parse to arrive at a DateTime, just a plain cast could be enough: `((DateTime)dReaderGameweekFixtures["fixtureDate"]).ToString("ddd dd")`

Comment: Adding "th" or any of the other suffixes seems tricky especially since those strings are not localized

Answer (score 1):

You need to format the string according to one of the available formats:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Pass it to `ToString` method.

Answer (score 0):

Have go on the link below, would suffice your need and increase your knowledge...

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format

Answer (score 0):

You should use ToString method of DateTime with format parameter

Check some info here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

```
Label fixtureDateLabel = new Label();
DateTime d = dReaderGameweekFixtures["fixtureDate"];
fixtureDateLabel.Text = d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```