# How to convert datetime field to string like 1st Feb 2011?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

How do I convert a datetime field to a string with the format `1st Feb 2011` in C#  ? `doj` is `datetime` field in sql server.

```
string DateOfJoin = dt.Rows[0]["DOJ"].ToString();//2011-02-01 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Is your string is `1st Jan 2015` or `2/1/2011 12:00:00 AM`? What is the type of your first column in that datatable?

Comment: i need like that format . day month year. my string is 2/1/2011 12:00:00 AM

Comment: And `2/1/2011` can be `1st Feb` or `2nd Jan` **not** `1st Jan`.

Comment: There are a lot of formats already available in `DataTime.ToString()`. If you want something more customized, you can try writing an extension method on `DateTime`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, `2/1/2011` can be 1st Feb or 2nd Jan **not** 1st Jan.

Second, let's parse your `string` to `DateTime`.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dt.Rows[0]["DOJ"].ToString(),
                                  "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or you can explicitly cast it to `DateTime`

```
DateTime dt = (DateTime)dt.Rows[0]["DOJ"];
```

Third, .NET does not have a built-in way in BCL to generate day suffix. But [Lazlow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63100/lazlow) [write a method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9130114/447156) for that which works seems okey to me as;

```
static string GetDaySuffix(int day)
{
    switch (day)
    {
        case 1:
        case 21:
        case 31:
            return "st";
        case 2:
        case 22:
            return "nd";
        case 3:
        case 23:
            return "rd";
        default:
            return "th";
    }
}
```

and you can this method like;

```
string DateOfJoin = String.Format("{0}{1} {2}",
                                  dt.Day,
                                  GetDaySuffix(dt.Day),
                                  dt.ToString("MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

which generates

[image]

Comment: Thanks For ur Effort.

Comment: @krishnamohan Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

use format below to get the similar without suffix [see explanation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 string DateOfJoin = dt.Rows[0]["DOJ"].ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");
```

However to get the suffix you'll need to break it up so that you get the day separate i.e.

```
string DateOfJoin = dt.Rows[0]["DOJ"].ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");
```

I would use below if you really need the suffix

```
string day = dt.Rows[0]["DOJ"].ToString("dd");
day = GetDaySuffix(Int32.Parse(day));
```

This using a function to add the suffix that I originally found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050805/getting-day-suffix-when-using-datetime-tostring)

```
  string GetDaySuffix(int day)
{
    switch (day)
    {
        case 1:
        case 21:
        case 31:
            return "st";
        case 2:
        case 22:
            return "nd";
        case 3:
        case 23:
            return "rd";
        default:
            return "th";
    }
}



 string DateOfJoin = String.Format("{0} {1}", day, dt.Rows[0]["DOJ"].ToString("MMMM yyyy"));
```

Not tested but should be useful start

Answer (score 0):

Try  this

```
 string DateOfJoin =Convert.ToDateTime( dt.Rows[0]["DOJ"]).ToString("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
 string DateOfJoin =Convert.ToDateTime( dt.Rows[0]["DOJ"]).ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");
```

Comment: giving error - no overload for  method tostring takes one argument

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the specified culture, long date strings can be achieved by casting the object to DateTime and then calling `ToString()` with the format parameter.

```
string DateOfJoin = ((DateTime)dt.Rows[0]["DOJ"]).ToString("D");
```

Further reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Edit: Formatting with things like '1st', '2nd', requires you to write a custom method which evaluates the day number and appends the correct string to it, something like:

```
private string GetSuffix(DateTime dt)
{
   if(dt.Days % 10 == 1)
   {
      return dt.Days.ToString() + "st";
   }
   else if(dt.Days % 10 == 2)
   {
      return dt.Days.ToString() + "nd";
   }
   else if(dt.Days % 10 == 3)
   {
      return dt.Days.ToString() + "rd";
   }
   else
   {
      return dt.Days.ToString() + "th";
   } 
}
```

And then add this part of the string, to a ToString("Y") of the DateTime, like:

```
string DateOfJoin = GetSuffix((DateTime)dt.Rows[0]["DOJ"]) + " " + ((DateTime)dt.Rows[0]["DOJ"]).ToString("Y");
```

Comment: Looks like first column is not a DateTime based on OP's comment.

Comment: getting output like this - Tuesday, February 01, 2011. but i need 1st Feb 2011

Answer (score 0):

```
Var dt = DateTime.Parse(DateOfJoin);
dt.ToString('F');
```

See bottom of the following page for more formats

[Msdn DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `F` as a `char`? I'm quite sure there is no overload like that.

Answer (score 0):

This tack can be accomplished with using the following approach:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2015, 01, 01);
// 1st Jan 2015
string s = Ordinal.Add(date.Day) + date.ToString(" MMM yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Here the `Ordinal` class is implemented as follows:

```
static class Ordinal {
    public static string Add(int num) {
        if(num <= 0) return num.ToString();
        switch(num % 100) {
            case 11:
            case 12:
            case 13:
                return num + "th";
        }
        switch(num % 10) {
            case 1: return num + "st";
            case 2: return num + "nd";
            case 3: return num + "rd";
            default: return num + "th";
        }
    }
}
```