# string manipulation for a password

Tags: powershell

Good day,

I'm trying to create a default password base of the date that is the user is starting. For example, if the user starts on "11/10/2018", the password should be 
"Sep10th2018!"

this is what I have. It "works" but I'm sure there should be a better way to doing this. I just don't know how. Just in case, this is not so much of an issue. Is more for learning sake. I'm trying to be better at PowerShell.

```
#   Generate Default Password
IF ($StartDate[0] -eq "0" -and $StartDate[1] -eq "1") {
    $Month = "Jan"
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "1") {$Day = "1st"}
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "2") {$Day = "2nd"}
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "3") {$Day = "3rd"} 
    Else {$Day = @($StartDate[3] + $StartDate[4] + "th")}
    $Year = @("20" + $StartDate[8] + $StartDate[9] + "!")
}
IF ($StartDate[0] -eq "0" -and $StartDate[1] -eq "2") {
    $Month = "Feb"
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "1") {$Day = "1st"}
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "2") {$Day = "2nd"}
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "3") {$Day = "3rd"} 
    Else {$Day = @($StartDate[3] + $StartDate[4] + "th")}
    $Year = @("20" + $StartDate[8] + $StartDate[9] + "!")
}    
IF ($StartDate[0] -eq "0" -and $StartDate[1] -eq "3") {
    $Month = "Mar"
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "1") {$Day = "1st"}
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "2") {$Day = "2nd"}
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "3") {$Day = "3rd"} 
    Else {$Day = @($StartDate[3] + $StartDate[4] + "th")}
    $Year = @("20" + $StartDate[8] + $StartDate[9] + "!")
}    
IF ($StartDate[0] -eq "0" -and $StartDate[1] -eq "4") {
    $Month = "Apr"
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "1") {$Day = "1st"}
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "2") {$Day = "2nd"}
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "3") {$Day = "3rd"} 
    Else {$Day = @($StartDate[3] + $StartDate[4] + "th")}
    $Year = @("20" + $StartDate[8] + $StartDate[9] + "!")
}    
IF ($StartDate[0] -eq "0" -and $StartDate[1] -eq "5") {
    $Month = "May"
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "1") {$Day = "1st"}
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "2") {$Day = "2nd"}
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "3") {$Day = "3rd"} 
    Else {$Day = @($StartDate[3] + $StartDate[4] + "th")}
    $Year = @("20" + $StartDate[8] + $StartDate[9] + "!")
}    
IF ($StartDate[0] -eq "0" -and $StartDate[1] -eq "6") {
    $Month = "Jun"
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "1") {$Day = "1st"}
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "2") {$Day = "2nd"}
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "3") {$Day = "3rd"} 
    Else {$Day = @($StartDate[3] + $StartDate[4] + "th")}
    $Year = @("20" + $StartDate[8] + $StartDate[9] + "!")
}    
IF ($StartDate[0] -eq "0" -and $StartDate[1] -eq "7") {
    $Month = "Jul"
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "1") {$Day = "1st"}
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "2") {$Day = "2nd"}
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "3") {$Day = "3rd"} 
    Else {$Day = @($StartDate[3] + $StartDate[4] + "th")}
    $Year = @("20" + $StartDate[8] + $StartDate[9] + "!")
}    
IF ($StartDate[0] -eq "0" -and $StartDate[1] -eq "8") {
    $Month = "Aug"
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "1") {$Day = "1st"}
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "2") {$Day = "2nd"}
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "3") {$Day = "3rd"} 
    Else {$Day = @($StartDate[3] + $StartDate[4] + "th")}
    $Year = @("20" + $StartDate[8] + $StartDate[9] + "!")
}    
IF ($StartDate[0] -eq "0" -and $StartDate[1] -eq "9") {
    $Month = "Sep"
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "1") {$Day = "1st"}
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "2") {$Day = "2nd"}
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "3") {$Day = "3rd"} 
    Else {$Day = @($StartDate[3] + $StartDate[4] + "th")}
    $Year = @("20" + $StartDate[8] + $StartDate[9] + "!")
}    
IF ($StartDate[0] -eq "1" -and $StartDate[1] -eq "0") {
    $Month = "Oct"
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "1") {$Day = "1st"}
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "2") {$Day = "2nd"}
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "3") {$Day = "3rd"} 
    Else {$Day = @($StartDate[3] + $StartDate[4] + "th")}
    $Year = @("20" + $StartDate[8] + $StartDate[9] + "!")
}    
IF ($StartDate[0] -eq "1" -and $StartDate[1] -eq "1") {
    $Month = "Nov"
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "1") {$Day = "1st"}
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "2") {$Day = "2nd"}
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "3") {$Day = "3rd"} 
    Else {$Day = @($StartDate[3] + $StartDate[4] + "th")}
    $Year = @("20" + $StartDate[8] + $StartDate[9] + "!")
}   
IF ($StartDate[0] -eq "1" -and $StartDate[1] -eq "2") {
    $Month = "Dec"
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "1") {$Day = "1st"}
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "2") {$Day = "2nd"}
    IF ($StartDate[3] -eq "0" -eq $StartDate[4] -eq "3") {$Day = "3rd"} 
    Else {$Day = @($StartDate[3] + $StartDate[4] + "th")}
    $Year = @("20" + $StartDate[8] + $StartDate[9] + "!")
}

[string]$password2 = @($Month + $Day + $Year)
$password = $password2 | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$password
```

Comment: Where are you getting `$StartDate` from - an AD user property or somewhere else? Knowing this might help with discerning a more elegant solution

Comment: I put in manually into a variable like; $StartDate = Read-Host "StartDate?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex to get the day suffix, and [format operator](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.powershell-using-the-f-format-operator.aspx) to build the password:

```
function Get-DateSuffix([datetime]$Date) {
    switch -regex ($Date.Day.ToString()) {
        '1(1|2|3)$' { 'th'; break }
        '.?1$'      { 'st'}
        '.?2$'      { 'nd'}
        '.?3$'      { 'rd'}
        default     { 'th'}
    }
}

[datetime]$StartDate = "11/10/2018"

$password = "{0:MMM}{1}{2}{3}!" -f $StartDate, $StartDate.Day, (Get-DateSuffix $StartDate), $StartDate.Year
```

Comment: shouldn't `'1(1|2|3)$' { 'th'}` have a break to avoid an array?

Answer (score 2):

Repurposing the elegant C# solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050805/getting-day-suffix-when-using-datetime-tostring/9130114#9130114), you can do it like this in PowerShell:

```
    function Get-DaySuffix($day)
    {
        switch ($day)
        {
            {$day -in (1,21,31)} {"st" }
            {$day -in (2,22)} { "nd" }
            {$day -in (3,23)} { "rd" }
            default { "th" }
        }
    }

    # Change to some other means of getting date - e.g. Read-Host
    $startDate = Get-Date "23/05/2007"

    # Get a collection of the month names (e.g. Jan, Feb, mar, etc)
    $months = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames

    # Build the password from the date parts
    $password = "$($months[$startDate.Month-1])$($startDate.Day)$(Get-DaySuffix $startDate.Day)$($startDate.Year)!"
```

In this case `$password` is set to `May23rd2007!`.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: you probably already know, but I have to state that that's a **very bad** password, if you can even call it that*

---

Most of this can be offloaded to the [`DateTime` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime), all except for the ordinal suffixes for the day of the month.

I would break it down into 3 steps:

1. Parse input date
2. Generate first half
3. Calculate the suffix
4. Append the year

---

```
# Parse the input date
$inputDate = Read-Host "Input date in the format MM/dd/yyyy"
$date = [datetime]::ParseExact($inputDate,'MM/dd/yyyy',$null)

# Generate first half 
$dateString = $date.ToString('MMMdd')

# Calculate the ordinal suffix
$day = $date.Day
if($day -in 1,21,31) {
    $dateString += 'st'
}
else if($day -in 2,22) {
    $dateString += 'nd'
}
else if($day -in 3,23) {
    $dateString += 'rd'
}
else {
    $dateString += 'th'
}

# Append the year:
$dateString += $date.ToString('yyyy!')
```