# What is date format for 07th November 2021?

Tags: c#, .net

I want the date format as 07th November 2021. Kindly let me know the format.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a custom date format, the `th` part I have no clue, but the rest should be quite straighforward. Check [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: You will have to special-case "1st", "2nd" and "3rd", for days > 3 others: "dd'th' MMMM yyyy"

Comment: @SᴇM quite close, but that would match `07` but not `07th`.

Comment: You've had excellent service/swift answers. Might you want to consider voting the answers and accepting one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050805/getting-day-suffix-when-using-datetime-tostring

Comment: Looks like the Ames Bond format.

Answer (score 2):

The tricky part is the "th", becasue it has to mutate to "st"/"nd"/"rd" for the some days of a month.

So these days require special-casing of this ordinal suffix, e.g:

```
string ordinalSuffix;
if (date.Day == 1 || date.Day == 21 || date.Day == 31)
    ordinalSuffix = "st";
else if (date.Day == 2 || date.Day == 22)
    ordinalSuffix = "nd";
else if (date.Day == 3 || date.Day == 23)
    ordinalSuffix = "rd";
else
    ordinalSuffix= "th";

string formatted = date.ToString($"dd'{ordinalSuffix}' MMMM yyyy");
```

You surely are aware that this works for English only. To support other languages, you might consider using a library like [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer/blob/main/readme.md).

Comment: What about 21, 22, 23, 30, 31?

Comment: I would store the `st`/`nd`/`rd`/`th` in a variable and do the `ToString` later, just to avoid repeating the `MMMM yyyy`.

Comment: @phuzi Good catch, edited

Comment: As @Cleptus stated, I would try and reduce it so that only have a single `date.ToString()` using a variable to store the suffix.

Comment: shorter version can use `%` : `if (date.Day % 10 == 1) ordinalSuffix = "st"`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this function here:

```
        public static string ToStringWithSuffix(this DateTime dt, string format) {   
        // The format parameter MUST contain [$suffix] within it, which will be replaced.   
        int day = dt.Day; string suffix = "";   
        // Exception for the 11th, 12th, & 13th   
        // (which would otherwise end up as 11st, 12nd, 13rd)   
        if (day % 100 >= 11 && day % 100 <= 13) {   
            suffix = "th";   
        }else{
            switch (day % 10) {   
                case 1: 
                    suffix = "st";   
                    break;   
                case 2:
                    suffix = "nd";   
                    break;   
                case 3:   
                    suffix = "rd";   
                    break;  
                default:   
                    suffix = "th";   
                    break;   
            }
        }
        // Convert the date to the format required, then add the suffix.   
    return dt.ToString(format).replace("[$suffix]",suffix);
}
```

You can call it like so:

```
DateTime(2021, 2, 21);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToStringWithSuffix("dd'[$suffix]' MMMM yyyy"));
```

You can also check the documentation on [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) if you need other formats.

Source: https://gist.github.com/woodss/006f28f01dcf371c2bd1

Comment: I like your logic, but consider adding a sample call, something like `DateTime dt = new DateTime(2021, 2, 21); Console.WriteLine(dt.ToStringWithSuffix("dd[$suffix] MMMM yyyy"));`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will consider your advice and I will edit my answer!